# Extract elements from nested JSON in Python2.7

Tags: python, json

I have following json string 'genes'.

```
[{'symbol': 'CSF3R', 'mentions': 13, 'variants': [{'key': 'T618I', 'matched': ['CSF3R T618I', 'T618I'], 'mentions': 13}]}, {'symbol': 'BCR', 'mentions': 2}, {'symbol': 'ABL1', 'mentions': 1}]
```

I would like to extract symbol, mentions, variants-key value and its mention.

My script is not able to match condition on variants. I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am running below code:

```
url = "https://hsgdigdhjsdgjshkjh/api/v2/article_info?"
token = "api_token=hsgdkjhökhjsgjfhkjshlhlshf"
x = "&pmid="

response_suggestions = requests.get(url + token + x + id)
genes = (response_suggestions.json()['genes'])                                                           
#print (genes)

x = 0
for symbol in genes:
    if ['genes'][x]['variants'][x] != None:
        print  str(response_suggestions.json()['genes'][x]['symbol']) + '\t' +
               str(response_suggestions.json()['genes'][x]['mentions']) + '\t' +
               str(response_suggestions.json()['genes'][x]['variants'][x]['key']))
               str(response_suggestions.json()['genes'][x]['variants'][x]['mentions']))
        x=x+1
    else:
        x=x+1
        continue
```

The expected output is:

```
CSF3R   13    T618I    13
BCR      2    -         -
ABL1     1    -         -
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!